# On TypeScript new CSSStyleSheet() receiving JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on a TypeScript project. At run time on this line I receive the following error:

```
var stylesheet:CSSStyleSheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
```

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that TypeScript code is not being compiled correctly to JavaScript. There is no such thing supported like new CSSStyleSheet () in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet):

> A `CSSStyleSheet` object is created and inserted into the document's `styleSheets` list automatically by the browser, when a style sheet is loaded for a document. As the `document.styleSheets` list cannot be modified directly, there's no useful way to create a new `CSSStyleSheet` object manually. ... To create a new stylesheet, insert a `<style>` or `<link>` element into the document.

Essentially, it is not possible to create a `CSSStyleSheet` object using normal constructor functions. You can only delegate it to the browser using HTML and get the result from that.